# PHP gettext for Lemonstand

Tags: php, gettext

PHP gettext is installed on my web server (running WAMP). However, the strings that have  within Lemonstand do not translate. I have my .po and .mo files with translations in them but nothing seems to happen. My locale path is correct. My locale PHP code is placed in a localization partial that is called from within my French header partial. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
$locale = "fr_CA";
if (isset($_GET["locale"]))
$locale = $_GET["locale"];
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
$path = 'locale';
bindtextdomain("default", $path);
textdomain("default");
bind_textdomain_codeset("default", 'UTF-8');
```

What could be causing the problem? I thought it might be server caching so I tried using this code instead but still no result:

```
$locale = "fr_CA";
$locales_root = "locale";
$domain = "default";
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
$filename = $locales_root.'/'.$locale.'/LC_MESSAGES/'.$domain.'.mo';
$mtime = filemtime($filename); // check its modification time
$filename_new = $locales_root.'/'.$locale.'/LC_MESSAGES/'.$domain.'_'.$mtime.'.mo';
if (!file_exists($filename_new)) {
copy($filename,$filename_new);
}
$domain_new = $domain.'_'.$mtime;
bindtextdomain($domain_new, $locales_root);
textdomain($domain_new);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain_new, 'UTF-8');
```

Thank you for your help!